# Print a document since a Sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script

*[**Example is more easy to Understand**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcSTM.png)*.I tried to print a google document  by through a side bar.
I have retrieved a script extract on the web.
My result is a printing the contents of the sidebar and not a google document printing .... oops
Can someone help me ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function initButtonImprimer() {
      var bouton = document.getElementById('button-imprimer');
      bouton.onclick = function(e) {
        print();
        return false;
      }
    }
    </script>
    </head>

    <body>
      ...
      <div>
       ...
        <input type="button" id="button-imprimer" value="Imprimer" />
        ...
      </div>
      ...
      <script type="text/javascript">
        initButtonImprimer();
      </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: huha? Can you please read over your question and try to see if you can make it more clear?

Comment: Hey Spncer ...here is. Is this understandable https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcSTM.png

Comment: So you would like to print the content of the document and not the content in the sidebar?

Comment: Exactly Spencer

Comment: Exactly Spencer.
is there a method ? i thought to the document  ID .

Comment: They way the sidebar and menu dialog are sand boxed I do not think this is possible